# Why is Readonly<T> assignable to T, but ReadonlyArray<T> is not assignable to Array<T>?

Tags: typescript

```
type Foo = {a: number}
let obj: Foo = {} as Readonly<Foo>
let arr: number[] = [] as ReadonlyArray<number>
```

I understand that the `ReadonlyArray` type removes any mutative `Array` methods, and that means the readonly array is not adhering to the expected interface of an array.

But I don't understand why readonly objects are considered safe to pass to a function that expects a mutable object. Technically, the readonly object is missing an implicit setter method, so it's not really adhering to the expected mutable interface.

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Foo%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20number%7D%0D%0Alet%20obj%3A%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20Readonly%3CFoo%3E%0D%0Alet%20arr%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%20as%20ReadonlyArray%3Cnumber%3E)

Comment: I wrote an ESLint plugin that might help: https://github.com/danielnixon/eslint-plugin-total-functions#total-functionsno-unsafe-assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadonlyArray` is, in fact, another type, so `Array` and `ReadonlyArray` are different structurally. As you noticed, instances of `ReadonlyArray` are missing some methods like `push` and `pop`.

It doesn't work like that with objects. There is no separate `ReadonlyObject` nor `ReadonlyObjectConstructor`. Many operations that should not be allowed are allowed:

```
type Foo = {a: number}

let mutable: Foo = { a: 0 };
let immutable: Readonly<Foo> = { a: 0 };

/**
 * Both work without error.
 */
mutable = immutable;
immutable = mutable;

/**
 * These two work as well.
 */
Object.assign(immutable, { foo: 1 });
Object.defineProperty(immutable, 'bar', {
    value: 2
});
```

TypeScript uses a structural type system. Two objects of exactly the same shape will be assignable to each other. However, the `readonly` modifier doesn't affect the structure, only behavior.