# How can I represent an immutable array of immutable objects?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define a class which takes as one of of its constructor parameters an array of objects, and I'd like to provide the guarantee that neither the array nor the objects in it will be modified. My current attempt uses the `readonly` modifier and the `Readonly<T>` generic and looks something like this:

```js
export type Foo = { foo: string };

export class Bar {
  readonly foo: Foo;
  readonly bars: Array<Readonly<Bar>>;

  constructor(
    foo: Readonly<Foo>,
    bars: Readonly<Array<Readonly<Bar>>>,
  ) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bars = bars;
  }
}
```

([Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiEJwLxwN5wBmmAXHAM4xQCWAdgOZwC+A3AFBuiSxwDGANgENy5OACFBUfGzhwowQQBMItfoiKl0mdrPlKVauACNJ5MgEEoUQYgA8AJQXLVdiVAB879jL4rKUAFdeGGgACh9ZYggyR30XWwwIdwAaCONTGKcDO0trO1jnNVs3TxSfAEppWVkYAAtqcgA6KJwNCB1quobGkyhRXF7yDqY2JiA))

However, this gives an error on the line `this.bars = bars;`, saying `The type 'readonly Readonly<Bar>[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Readonly<Bar>[]'.ts(4104)`.

After some searching, I found a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62226291/46387) of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54155595/46387) which seem, if I understand them correctly, to indicate that mutable arrays and `readonly`/`Readonly<T>` arrays can't be assigned to one another.

How, then, can I represent the immutability contract I'm trying to express? I'm using Typescript 4.5.2 and my `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879327/deepreadonly-object-typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `ReadonlyArray`.

```
export type Foo = { foo: string };

export class Bar {
  readonly foo: Foo;
  readonly bars: ReadonlyArray<Readonly<Bar>>;

  constructor(
    foo: Readonly<Foo>,
    bars: ReadonlyArray<Readonly<Bar>>,
  ) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bars = bars;
  }
}
```

In the statement `readonly bars: ReadonlyArray<Readonly<Bar>>`, the meaning of the different parts is as follows:

- `readonly` states that the `bars` property is readonly, it prevents you from writing `this.bars = whatever`.
- `ReadonlyArray` states that the array is readonly, it prevents you from writing `this.bars[0] = whatever`.
- `Readonly<Bar>` states that the elements of the array are readonly, it prevents `this.bars[0].foo = whatever`.

Comment: Huh, and you can even still call it with a mutable array (e.g. `new Bar({foo:'foo'}, [])`). That's perfect, thanks!